# Memcached concurrency w/ lighttpd php

Tags: php, lighttpd, memcached, socket

I'm having an issue with memcached. Not sure if it's memcached, php, or tcp sockets but everytime I try a benchmark with 50 or more concurrency to a page with memcached, some of those request failed using apache ab. I get the (99) Cannot assign requested address error.

When I do a concurrency test of 5000 to a regular phpinfo() page. Everything is fine. No failed requests.

It seems like memcached cannot support high concurrency or am I missing something? I'm running memcached with the -c 5000 flag.

---

Server: (2) Quad Core Xeon 2.5Ghz, 64GB ram, 4TB Raid 10, 64bit OpenSUSE 11.1

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out just in case anyone have the same problems:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278167/memcached-concurrency-w-lighttpd-php/1280648#1280648

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your out of sockets.  What does netstat show?  See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/140995.